# Clingo "info: tuple ignored"

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

I am doing an ASP task and encountered something that I could not solve on my own.

:- a(M, D, *), #sum { TP : b(*, M, TP) } != D.

This is the line of code where clingo gives me "info: tuple ignored: TP", specifying the "TP" right after the opening "{".

What I am trying here is realizing the logic : for every M, when you add up all the TP from various sources (sources are where the placeholder "_" is placed) that are transported to this market M, the total of TP must not be equal to the M's D.

Specifying the first parameter of b as in:

:- a(M, D, _), #sum { F, TP : b(F, M, TP) } != D.

or

:- a(M, D, F), #sum { F, TP : b(F, M, TP) } != D.

does not help.

Can somebody help me what I am doing wrong here? If any more context is needed, please feel free to comment so.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the rule you show, please fix it